# Working with slots and scoped css in Vuejs3

Tags: vuejs3

I ran into the issue with Vue3 with slots and scoped css. Basically, I want to render some html based on component specific/scoped css.

Lets call the component Styler . This is how I would do that:

```
//Styler.vue
[...]
<template>
    <article class="main">
        <slot />
    </article>
</template>

<style lang="css" scoped src="../css/styler.css"></style>
```

This result in all css selectors in styler.css to be propped with `v-data-{rand-styler}` as expected, e.g. `h1[v-data-{rand-styler}]` or `.main h1[v-data-{rand-styler}]` if I nest it.

The problem is that when I use Styler

```
<Styler>
    <h1>Style me Styler, style me away<h1>
</Styler>
```

the resulting html will not have h1 propped with `v-data-{rand-styler}` only article will.

I would expect `h1` to have scope attribute, because in rendering in the context of Styler.

How one should work around it?

Comment: After working with Vue for a few years, I concluded scoped styles was just not worth bothering with because of various edge cases and reasons VS manual naming + un-scoped or SASS/LESS or whatever setup with an organised folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slots are child components, so you would have to use the [`:deep()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) selector to target them.

Then you get rules like `[v-data-{rand-styler}] h1`, which will affect child components (make sure the slot is not a root element, otherwise it will get a different attribute).

---

But it looks like your styler component is designed specifically to apply styles to children, so it is probably easier to use your own attribute or class to make sure only children are affected:

```html
<template>
    <article class="main styler-styles">
        <slot />
    </article>
</template>
```

and

```css
.styler-styles h1{
  ...
}
```